# Text to Image/PDF converter in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, image-processing

Is there any script, that takes HTML formatted text(including html tag elements) from mysql database and generates a image/PDF for a web application.

Ex HTML text: hello < h1 > World < /h1> It's a < span style="font-size:24";>good< /span> day.

It should read all the tags and display content on the Image accordingly.

I tried working with PHP, but it unable to process the HTML tags moreover it is displaying HTML tags on the image as it is from database.

I also like to know is there any third party service that serves my purpose?
If so, is there any resource to learn and implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another alternative, this one based on a real web browser engine - WebKit. It's the same one that powers Safari and Google Chrome, so it should be way more powerful than most other custom HTML-TO-PDF solutions.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: Thanks for the link.
I may sound little dumb but do you know any step by step tutorial thing to use this service.

Comment: It's a command line application. That means you'll probably use either the backtick operator, or one of [Program Execution Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php). As to what parameters to give in command line - just look at the website, they've got a [manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) and everything.